# How to extract a free text token from user input

Tags: watson-conversation

As shown in many examples, you can easily extract entity values from a response, as in the following dialog:

- Watson: OK! What kind of music would you like to hear?
- User: Symphonic
- Watson: OK, playing symphonic

You can get the same response from Watson when the user is saying "I want to hear symphonic", instead of just "Symphonic", provided that:

- Intent #i_want_to_hear has examples: "Symphonic", "I want hear Rock", "I'd like to listen to Jazz"
- Entity @genre has value @genre:symphonic
- The node condition is @genre
- The node output text is "OK! Playing @genre"

Can I achieve the same robustness if the question is about free text (a name) instead of an entity? For instance:

- Watson: What is your name?
- User: Anna
- Watson: Nice to meet you, Anna

If node condition is true and output text is "Nice to meet you, input_text", this is not going to work on an answer such as "My name is Anna".

I cannot follow the @genre approach described above because I cannot create an entity "name" with a different value for each possible name.

If there is no simple solution, maybe can I take the last word in the user response, as it is always one of:

- Anna
- I am Anna
- My name is Anna
- It is Anna

So my second question is: How to extract the last word from an answer to use it in the output text and in the context?

Thanks

Comment: Getting a persons name is actually quite hard. Even if you solve above, it's going to have more issues. I blogged about it recently. https://sodoherty.com/2016/09/11/what-is-your-name/

Answer (score 0):

You can extract parts of input from `input.text` with regexps using the `.extract` method defined in String type:

From our [doc](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation):

**`String.extract(String regexp, Integer groupIndex)`**

Custom method. This method returns a string extracted by specified group index of the input regular expression. The following series shows an example of how the .extract method works:

The input.text is "Hello 123456".

DialogNode:

```
"context" : {
    "number_extract" : "<? input.text.extract('[\\d]+',0) ?>"
}
```

Note that in order to process \d as the regular expression, you must insert another \ before it, to escape the second .

Result:

```
"context" : {
    "number_extract" : "123456"
}
```